# Problema com return

Tags: javascript, node.js, assincronismo

Estou com problema com `return` já que o `node` é todo assíncrono.

```
var myFUNC = function(A, B) {
    A.every(function(AA) {        
        return (AA === B);
    });

    return true;
};

if(!myFUNC(...)) {
    ....
}
```

obviamente a função sempre retorna `true` mas ela não deveria fazer isso, como estou começando com `node`, não sei como resolver este impasse.

Ela deveria seguir a seguinte lógica:

- varre a `array` `A`
- se `AA === B` for `false` ele para de percorrer a `array` e retorna `false`
- se nenhum item da `array` retornar `false` então retorna `true`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

O problema do seu código não é que ele está sendo executado asincronamente. O problema é que você está ignorando o resultado da chamada `A.every(...)` (que é executada de forma síncrona) - se todos os `return (AA === B)` forem verdade, então `every` retorna `true` (ou `false` se algum deles não forem verdadeiros).

Você pode reescrever a sua função da seguinte forma:

```
var myFUNC = function(A, B) {
    var todosIguais = A.every(function(AA) {        
        return (AA === B);
    });

    return todosIguais;
};

if(!myFUNC(...)) {
    ....
}
```

Comment: não havia reparado nisso, +1